# Ionic 2 Android Production Build tries to build iOS as well

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I finished my Android app in Ionic 2.

I did not add iOS.

```
ionic build --release --prod android
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: The provided path "/Users/USER/App_path/platforms/ios" is not a Cordova iOS project.
```

This folder does not even exists because I don't want to build for iOS.

How can I fix this?

I tried to add iOS as platform but not all plugins work for iOS so it returned errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I solved using the -d flag to show debug output

```
cordova -d platform add ios
ionic build ios
ionic emulate ios
```

My debug output showed that I need to set a JAVA_HOME environment variable and then I needed to add JAVA and ANT to the path.